# Authorize shiny apps application via oauth browser flow

Tags: shiny, oauth, shinyapps

I am trying to deploy a shiny app with oauth authorization to shinyapps.io. I have created a simple template app for illustration (see below). I am able to deploy and launch the app. However, the login button has no effect, nothing happens. No message is being displayed (not even "Authentication Failed.").

The logs say that the app is "Waiting for authentication in browser..." and "Please point your browser to the following url: ..." When I manually enter the provided url, the authentication provider's website opens, I log in, and am being redirected to the app (in a new tab), but then again, nothing happens.

Thank you for your help.

```
library(shiny)
library(httr)

# OAuth application details
korap_app <- oauth_app("korap-client", key = "tmNm9RMf3hnFMpnTN4NbFT", secret = NULL, redirect_uri = "https://danieljach.shinyapps.io/KED_interface/")
korap_endpoint <- oauth_endpoint(NULL, authorize = "settings/oauth/authorize", access = "api/v1.0/oauth2/token", base_url = "https://korap.ids-mannheim.de")

# UI
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("OAuth Shiny App Template"),
  mainPanel(
    actionButton("loginButton", "Login with OAuth"),
    textOutput("authStatus")
  )
)

# Server
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  # Reactive value to store authentication status
  authenticated <- reactiveVal(FALSE)
  
  # OAuth login event
  observeEvent(input$loginButton, {
    # Open the browser for user authentication
    token <- oauth2.0_token(korap_endpoint, korap_app, scope = "search match_info", cache = FALSE)
    
    # Check if authentication is successful
    if (!is.null(token)) {
      authenticated(TRUE)
      output$authStatus <- renderText("Authentication Successful!")
    } else {
      output$authStatus <- renderText("Authentication Failed.")
    }
  })
  
  # Display content based on authentication status
  observe({
    if (authenticated()) {
      # Display authenticated content here
    } else {
      # Display content for non-authenticated users
    }
  })
}

# Run the app
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0):

A description of the underlying problem and a work-around are available here:

[answer on the RKorAPClient github page](https://github.com/KorAP/RKorAPClient/issues/13#issuecomment-1906542809)

Credit goes to the RKorAPClient developer [kupietz](https://github.com/kupietz).

Here is the working code.

```
library(shiny)
library(RKorAPClient)

# UI
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Login Shiny App Template"),
  mainPanel(
    textInput("accessToken", "Please enter your access token here."),
    actionButton("loginButton", "Enter."),
    textOutput("authStatus"),
    textInput("userQuery", "Please enter a search word."),
    actionButton("queryGo", "Search."),
    tableOutput("queryResults")
  )
)

# Server
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  # Reactive value to store authentication status
  authenticated <- reactiveVal(FALSE)
  rv <- reactiveValues(kco = NULL)
  # login event
  observeEvent(input$loginButton, {
    # use user token to open connection
    rv$kco <- new("KorAPConnection", accessToken = input$accessToken)
    
    # Check if connection is successful
    if (!is.null(reactive(rv$kco))) {
      authenticated(TRUE)
      output$authStatus <- renderText("Authentication Successful!")
    } else {
      output$authStatus <- renderText("Authentication Failed.")
    }
  })
  
  # query event
  observeEvent(input$queryGo, {
    output$queryResults <- renderTable(corpusQuery(rv$kco, input$userQuery, context = '3', metadataOnly = FALSE) %>% 
                                         fetchNext() %>%
                                         slot('collectedMatches'))
  })
}

# Run the app
shinyApp(ui, server)
```